# Is there a regrex script that can be used to extract texts by defining a start and an end in a text file

Tags: python, regex

Is there a regrex script that can be used to extract texts by defining a start and an end in a text file. For example in the text attached, I would like to extract only the portions starting with TTAA and ending with '='. I am not interested with other parts of the texts such as TTBB TTCC TTDD.

Here is a part of the text file I am working on:

202103162300 TTAA 16231 03808 99025 08635 02005 00294 07635 01513 92940 11080
04011 85639 06670 03018 70204 03569 01516 50576 24164 00522
40734 36753 36020 30927 52740 35023 25042 62340 35527 20179
60970 34521 15361 54579 33516 10617 58778 33514 88232 65346
35523 88108 59977 32014 77999 31313 44108 82315==
202103162300 TTBB 16238 03808 00025 08635 11014 08432 22994 07239 33992 07454
44979 07057 55975 07259 66972 08466 77971 09068 88963 10476
99953 11480 11918 11079 22892 09473 33853 06670 44838 06671
55801 04269 66778 02876 77735 00976 88722 01770 99702 03369=

Comment: You can use `TTAA[\d\s]+=`. \d stands for digit, \s stands for whitespace. Good site where you can try regex is [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/). There is cheatsheet as well. Next time please do not insert whole file content, short example would be just enought.

Comment: Many thanks indeed David. The link you provided has helped a million times!